# passing the same file path to command after first command is done executing in an alias

Tags: shell, command-line, sh

I am dumping make test output to a text file

```
make test > & ~/Desktop/makeTestOutput.txt
```

now  I want to make an alias in a way that once the make test dumping is done the path `~/Desktop/makeTestOutput.txt` should be used by next command I made `fetest` interpret and present readable data in Terminal.

I was thinking to do this `make test > & $1 | fetest $1` but that doesnt pipe the file path to `fetest`.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases handle arguments automatically and it is not possible to do what you want with simply using aliases. You should use functions instead. Check here for more details:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-alias

Comment: I do not know shell scripting.